# Wrap text in image within specific pixels box with dynamic font and text size

Tags: php, word-wrap

I have an image with multiple elements on it (other merged images), within this image there is a specific area where i want to insert text in. The text length is dynamic as i have several strings to be added randomly.

The question is, is it possible or is there a function that will receive the pixels boundaries and the text, and then adjust the font so the text can all fit within these boundaries?

I tried several functions including imagettfbbox() or through wrapping the string, but it still have to rely on a fixed font size?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is no such function. You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php to calculate the bounding box size of the text for a given font size. If the bounding box is to big, reduce the font size. Continue doing this until the bounding box is small enough to fit in your target bounding box or font size is 1 (or 0?).